# What does gdate mean in this shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I need to maintain this shell script:

```
export DAYDAY=`gdate --date "30 days ago" +"%Y%m%d"` 
if [ -d $TMP/AA/$DAYDAY]; then
    rm -r $TMP/AA/$DAYDAY  
fi
```

But I can't run it because it can't find `gdate`; this code is to clear the log directory that is exactly 30 days old.

Comment: Write in terminal 'man gdate'

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry - 'man gdate' won't work if there's no command named gdate. On my system: 'No manual entry for gdate'

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11misc/X11misc-20/pkg-config/pkg-config-0.25/glib-1.2.10/gdate.c

Comment: Thanks you, i can run it, i change 'gdate' to 'date'

Answer (score 7):

It's **G**NU's `date`; called `gdate` on BSD-related systems to differentiate it from their own `date`.

---

I work on Linux in a 90% Mac office and quite a few of my colleagues' scripts reference things like `gsed` and `gdate`. Where I couldn't fix this properly with a switch on `$OSTYPE` I eventually capitulated and did this:

```
sudo ln -s $(which date) /bin/gdate
```

This symlinks `gdate` to `date`.

This is quite safe because there should never be a `gdate` (or a `gsed`, `gtar` or `gmake`), for the version installed on GNU/Linux *is* the GNU version, obviously.

You could also alias the command of course, but this carries over users and shells. It is in effect aliasing the whole program.

Answer (score 6):

On *nix systems other than Linux it's fairly common for the GNU flavor of utilities to be installed prefixed with a `g` (e.g. `gmake`, `gtar`, etc). In this case, it's likely this refers to the GNU flavor of the `date` command.  So, since you are on Linux, just change it to `date`:

```
export DAYDAY=`date --date "30 days ago" +"%Y%m%d"` 
if [ -d $TMP/AA/$DAYDAY]; then
    rm -r $TMP/AA/$DAYDAY  
fi
```

Comment: Very thanks, i change and can run it. Im newbie with Linux and very difficult to learn it. Thanks you again FatalError